# Управление заливкой svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg

На HTML - странице присутствует векторное изображение в формате .SVG. Подгружено при помощи тэга object:

```html
<object id="somesvg" type="image/svg+xml" data="somepath" id='object'></object>
```

Разметка SVG-шки содержит определение стиля заливки:

```html
...
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .fil0 {fill:none}
    .fil1 {fill:black}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 ...
```

Пытаюсь при помощи JS реализовать изменение заливки этого изображения. Несколько разноцветных блоков, при клике на каждый из которых должен меняться цвет изображения на цвет фона этого блока:

```html
<script>
$(".color_change").click( function() {
 var color = $(this).css('background-color'); 
 var object = document.getElementById("somesvg");
  var svgDocument = object.contentDocument;
  var svgb = svgDocument.getElementsByClassName("fil1");
  svgb1[0].setAttribute("fill", color);
  });
</script>
```

Скрипт успешно добавляет свойство *fill* к элементу класса **.fil1**, что видно в консоли, однако заливка SVG - изображения на странице остается неизменной. В чем моя ошибка?

P.S. Менять разметку .SVG-файла нельзя, таких файлов довольно большое количество.

Comment: Элементы класса .fil1 - "<path>".

Comment: попробуйте воспользоваться `important`

Comment: Вроде стили и атрибуты это разные вещи

Comment: Спасибо! Помогла вот такая конструкция : $(svgb1[0]).attr('style','fill:'+color);

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо задавать элементу не атрибут **fill**, а **style**! 
Вместо строки:

```html
svgb1[0].setAttribute("fill", color);
```

стоит использовать другую конструкцию:

```html
$(svgb1[0]).attr('style','fill:'+color);
```